# Is there a usecase to create separate indices on the foreign keys of junction/associative table?

Tags: postgresql, index, foreign-key, index-tuning, primary-key

Imagine an **associative/junction** table `junction_table_` with (pseudocode) columns like:

```
id_of_table_x REFERENCES TABLE X
id_of_table_y REFERENCES TABLE Y

PRIMARY KEY (id_of_table_x, id_of_table_y)
```

So `id_of_table_x` and `id_of_table_y` are foreign keys referencing some primary keys of other tables and are used as composite primary key.

Now I could add:

```
CREATE INDEX some_index ON junction_table_ (id_of_table_x);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX some_index ON junction_table_ (id_of_table_y);
```

Would this have any (positive) effect?

What would be a valid use case for separate indices on the single columns?

e.g. queries that WHERE-filter on one of the two foreign keys within a join or delete operations which need to check whether the target is still referenced - do they profit from separate, additonal indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate index for the first column of your primary key (`id_of_table_x` in your example) because Postgres will happily use that  index in every situation where it would use the single-column index on the first column.

If you very often delete rows from the referenced table, then adding another index on the second column helps validating the foreign key during deleting.

The index on the second column might help for joins that only use that (but not the first column).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please also explain why the index doesn’t provide any benefit on the first column, while it does on the second? What if i filter on the first column in a join, or delete something in table `X` that is referenced by `id_of_table_x`? Thanks!

Comment: Because index columns are used from left to right. Any query using the single-column index will also use the two-column index with that column as the first column.

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Thanks for the additional info! For everyone who finds this, there’s also a thorough explanation here in the PostgreSQL docs that explains how this works for different index types and especially the default B-Tree indices: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html